# how to upload .flv to remote red5 server LIVE in real time?

Tags: red5, live-streaming

I want to do live webcast of some ceremonies. I can record .flv files using my webcam and ffmpeg software. Now, if I hire a red5 media server from some hosting company so that visitors can download from that website. Now my problem is how can I upload .flv files LIVE ( when video shooting is still in progress ) 
Please help how to achieve this

Comment: Possible answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982488/application-for-live-video-streaming-using-red5-server?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I assume by recording them you mean you are saving them to disk and are not streaming the video? If this is the case you simply need to use an upload form or have ftp / scp access to the hosted server. Pick one of the apps installed and place your flv files in the applications "streams" directory. Once the files are in-place you'll need a way to play them back, which will require a player (plenty of free ones out there like jwplayer). Hopefully this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Currently I am doinf offline. i.e. recording .flv and then uploading to the server when recording is finished. But  I want to do it LIVE when shooting is going on at the same time in realtime I have to upload live stream to the server. I want to know which software I have to use for that. ( If I want to upload to Adobe Flash Server I can use Adobe Flsh live media encoder. But I want to stream to Red5 server and want to know whichsoftwate I can use with it legally.

Comment: You can use FMLE, but you'd be violating the terms of their EULA. Some other options are Xsplit (http://www.xsplit.com/), Wirecast (http://www.telestream.net/wirecast/overview.htm), Tricaster (http://www.newtek.com/products/tricaster-855/tc855-compare.html), or Vidblaster (http://www.vidblaster.com/)

Comment: Yes. I  want the legal solution. Thank you so much for giving me so may options.